# Syntax error to get the 6th Business day after 25th of the month plus 5 business days

Tags: sql, syntax, cognos-10

Im working on a report that needs to show the exact date to determine who incurred late submission of charges. I added 3 queries and the last one to find the business day after the 25th of the month is giving me "An error occurred while performing operation 'sqlPrepareWithOptions' status = '239'

Can you help me please? The data item is 5 BUSINESS DAYS AFTER 25 and here's the query below:

```
CASE WHEN _day_of_week( _add_days( [FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH] , 5 ) ) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
     THEN '1'
     WHEN _day_of_week( _add_days( [FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH] , 6 ) ) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
     THEN '1'
     WHEN _day_of_week( _add_days( [FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH] , 7 ) ) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 
     THEN '1'
     WHEN _day_of_week( _add_days( [FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH] , 5 ) ) BETWEEN 6 AND 7 
     THEN '0'
     ELSE '0'
END
```

These are the 2 other queries that are working just fine:

LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH

_add_days (_first_of_month (CURRENT_DATE), -1)

FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH

```
CASE

WHEN EXTRACT( DAY , _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 2) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 2)
WHEN EXTRACT( DAY, _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH], - 3) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 3)
WHEN EXTRACT( DAY, _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH], - 4) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 4)
WHEN EXTRACT( DAY, _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH], - 5) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 5)
WHEN EXTRACT( DAY, _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH], - 6) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 6)
WHEN EXTRACT( DAY, _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH], - 7) ) = 25
THEN _add_days([LAST DAY OF LAST MONTH] , - 7)
ELSE CURRENT_DATE
END
```

Comment: Is `[FIND 25TH DAY OF MONTH]` a column here? Or a function?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive. *Issue with Query* is meaningless to a future reader here who is scanning a list of search results. Your title should describe an actual problem or question, and *issue with query* doesn't do so. Every single SQL question posted here has been about an *issue with query*.

Comment: I edited my description and included the 2 queries I created and used